# How to replace group attribute of a svg?

Tags: javascript

**Here is my javascript code**

```
svgString = svgString.replace(new RegExp('pointerevents', 'g'), "none");
```

**Here is my html code**

```
<g>
    <image clip-path="url(#clippath)" filter="url(#filterimg)" xlink:href="" x="0" y="0" height="200" width="200" pointer-events='inherit'/>
    <g id="pathgroup" pointer-events='inherit'></g>
</g>
```

> pointer-events='inherit' not getting change , how to replace "inherit" with "none".

Answer (score 1):

This should work providing your svg is embedded in a valid html page:

```
document.getElementById('pathgroup').setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");
```